# Cannot debug qt app - Debugging has finished

Tags: qt, debugging

I have a QT app which I'm trying to debug with no success.
I get the following application output: 
Debugging starts
Debugging has finished

and nothing happens.
I'm using MSVC2012 x64 compiler.
The app runs fine in release mode or if I choose to run it (not debug it) in debug mode.
any idea?
thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok. I got the problem - the debugger that was used was the cdb.exe of the x86 version.
I changed it to x64 and everything is working as expected.

Comment: It also can be a forgotten exit() call on the code, like the one I found in my code after spending 2 hours trying to identify why my debugging was being ended with no stack trace at all..

Answer (score 0):

It happenned to me when I was loading with QtCreator 3 a project that I had first use with a previous release. Deleting .pro.user files and rebuilding solved.